# How to switch the installed location of React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Hi I'm new to **React Native**.
I have followed [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) to set up the **React Native** environment.

I have **installed** **React Native** by the following comment in the **directory C://**

```
npm install -g create-react-native-app
```

Then run the followed the commands to create a new **React Native** project called "AwesomeProject" in the **directory D://**

```
create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
```

And when I try to start the project by the comment

```
npm start
```

It shows that like in an image below, don't know what to do, can't proceed further.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there `start` script available in `package.json`

Comment: where is package.json located. I can't see even a AppData directory.!!!

Comment: Is there a way to remove all the files related to React Native?

Comment: `create-react-native-app AwesomeProject` command create a new project with folder name `AwesomeProject`. Inside this folder you should have `package.json`.

Comment: start script is not present. Only "{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.11.1"
  }
}
is available

Comment: I suggest, Create your react-native project using `react-native init AppName`

Comment: Its working. If it is the better way to create project then why the document have some other. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165557/discussion-between-kishan-mundha-and-arnold-brown).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for blank project start in react-native.

```
react-native init ProjectName
```

Then you can start your project easily.